# Flutter Alert dialog Utils issue

Tags: flutter, dart, alert

Hi I am using custom alert dialog in my flutter project initially its working fine. but as of now not working
Anyone can help me to resolve these issue.
and please tell me the issues in these code because I need to understand so that. thanks

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';

class DialogUtils {
  static DialogUtils _instance = new DialogUtils.internal();

  DialogUtils.internal();

  factory DialogUtils() => _instance;

  static void showCustomDialog(BuildContext context,
      {required String title,
        String okBtnText = "Ok",
        required String message,
        required String cancelBtnText,
        required Function okBtnFunction,
        required Function cancelBtnFunction,

      }) {

showDialog(
  barrierColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
    context: context,
    builder: (_) {
      return Theme(
        data: ThemeData(dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white ),
        child: AlertDialog(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18.0))),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),

          title:  Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                 mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:10.0),
                        child: Image.asset("assets/images/mojarto_logo.png",
                        scale: 12,
                        )

                      )//
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Positioned(
                right: 0.0,
                bottom: 2.8,
                child: IconButton(onPressed: () {
                 Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                }, icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                )
              ),
            ],
          ),
          content: Text(message,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),

          actions: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: InkWell(
                     onTap: () {
                       okBtnFunction();
                     },
                      child: new Container(
                        // color: Colors.red,
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          border: new Border.all(
                            color:  HexColor("#EC1C24")
                          ),
                          borderRadius:
                          new BorderRadius.circular(3),
                        ),
                        child: new Center(
                            child:Text(okBtnText,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white
                              ),
                            ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: new InkWell(
                         onTap: () {
                           cancelBtnFunction();
                         },
                          child: new Container(
                              width: 40,
                              height: 40,
                              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                // color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                border: new Border.all(
                                  color: HexColor("#EC1C24")

                                ),
                                borderRadius:
                                new BorderRadius.circular(3),
                              ),
                              child: new Center(
                                child:Text(cancelBtnText,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                  color : HexColor("#EC1C24")
                                  ),

                                ),
                              ),
                          ))),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 60,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what problems you are having. any stack traces?

Answer (score 0):

Try this dialog. OTPTextField

```
showDataAlert() {
showDialog(
    barrierDismissible: false,
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(
              20.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 10.0,
        ),
        title: Text(
          "OTP Verify",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
        ),
        content: Container(
          height: 250,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Please enter otp ",
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: OTPTextField(
                    length: 6,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    fieldWidth: 35,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 13,
                    ),
                    textFieldAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    fieldStyle: FieldStyle.underline,
                    onCompleted: (pin) {
                      print(pin);

                      otpNo.value = TextEditingValue(text: pin.toString());
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 60,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print(otpNo.text);
                      // Navigator.pop(context);
                      if (otpNo.text.toString().length == 6) {
                        OTPSendVerify();
                      } else {
                        ToastDialog("Please enter otp", context);
                      }
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    child: otpverifying
                        ? Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ))
                        : Text(
                            "OTP Verify",
                          ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
```

}

showDataAlert();